# Passing a value to bean in commandButton in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

How can I pass a variable to the managed bean using h:commandButton in JSF 1.2. We are having `<f:param>` and `<f:attribute>` which works in JSF 2. Is there any similar way like that in JSF 1.2 to pass value.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f:setPropertyActionListener` for that:

```
    <h:commandButton style="display: none;"
        action="#{chAction.selectClient}" immediate="true">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{chAction.selectedClientId}"
            value="#{res.clientId}" />
    </h:commandButton>
```